# How to find the lowest value and the corresponding date SQL-Server 2014

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, select

I have the sample data [See the SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/5d6e6/1). I want to find the lowest value from the value column and the date of lowest value from the uploaded-date column. I tried the following query and it is not properly working and showing all values.

```
SELECT
    username,
    MIN(Value1) AS MinValue1,
    CASE 
        WHEN value1 = MIN(value1) THEN uploaded_date
    END
    AS MinDate
FROM
    test

GROUP BY
    username
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the [`RANK`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176102.aspx) window function to find the minimal value for each username:

```
SELECT username, value1, uploaded_date
FROM   (SELECT username, value1, uploaded_date,
               RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY username ORDER BY value1 ASC) AS rk
        FROM   test) t
WHERE  rk = 1
```

**[SQLFIddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/5d6e6/6/0)**

Comment: Thanks, It is working like a charm. I will accept your answer in 5 minutes. Any suggestions why my approach is not working? or how that can be aggregated.

Comment: Your original query is mixing aggregate and non-aggregate terms, which is not allowed. The other two answers demonstrate ways to separate the aggregate terms from the row terms with a subquery, while mine uses window functions instead.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT test. username,value1,MIN(uploaded_date  )FROM
(Select MIN(value1) MinValue1,username from test group by username ) A
INNER JOIN
test 
ON A.MinValue1 = test.Value1
AND A.username = test.username
GROUP BY
test. username,value1
```

Your query did not work because you were using the columns in the select list so the Group by clause will group all distinct values into each row

Comment: Can you please update the query because there is a small bug. In the case when user enter same value for value1 it shows all the values. Can you please update it to make only one row (first one).

Answer (score 0):

i hope this will help you

```
  ;with CTE as(
    SELECT username,
      MIN(Value1) AS MinValue1
  FROM
      test
  GROUP BY 
    username
  )

  select c.username,MinValue1,dt.uploaded_date from CTE c
  cross apply(select top 1 uploaded_date from test where value1=c.MinValue1 and username=c.username order by uploaded_date desc) dt
```

Answer (score -1):

```
select Value1, update_date from test order by Value1 limit 1
```